# document.addEventListener not working on Ios 13.3

Tags: javascript, ios, addeventlistener

I try to make a small correction on old code, the problem comes from the method:

document.addEventListener

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {return returnCharCode(event);});

function returnCharCode(event) {
   alert("This is the: " + event.keyCode);
}
```

when i test this on android and ios 12.4 it works but on an iphone x with ios 13.xxx nothing is displayed

Comment: Maybe iOS 13, or rather the iphone x, blocks the alert. Where to are you returning the `undefined` returned by `returnCharCode`? Where do you expect the return value to be received and used?

Comment: The method returnCharCode I added it just for the test.
otherwise the CharCode is used in another method depending on the character typing we display forms !

Comment: I mean `return` here: `function(event) {return ...}` is totally useless. The function is called from the event queue, and that's where the execution returns when the callback is finished. The event queue ignores the return value, it doesn't do anything with it nor it passes it anywhere.

Comment: Discovered similar issue when testing on an iPhone 6s with IOS 13.4.1. Web app is a blank white screen and error log says addEventListener is not a function. Had to revert code back to deprecated addListener function. Any ideas why?